# I want a script to run after the ajax finishes its work?

Tags: javascript

I have an image that is loaded on screen by an Ajax , and i want a button to appear after the image is fully loaded on screen

I want a script to run after the ajax finishes its work ?

Can anyone help

Comment: No source code = nothing to work with. Please edit your question and display the relevant source code. It would be a good idea to show your own attempts and explain why you think it isn't functioning as intended.

Comment: @torazaburo I could think of many reasons why people would use ajax to request image paths and load them in that way. It could be a dynamic images gallery for all we know. Loading images into an `img` tag without the use of ajax would require you to manually input those images leaving you with a static page/content.

Comment: @Mody : Please tell us if you have any doubts ?

Comment: @NewToJS What do you mean by "request image paths"? Anyway, excuse my ignorance, but once I have a blob of data coming back from the ajax call, exactly how are you planning display it on the page? I was under the impression that images were displayed on web pages using the `img` tag. Are you suggesting plugging the retrieved AJAX data into the `src` attribute of the `img` tag using data URLs? by the way, I can easily display dynamic images by creating on-demand `img` tags, or replacing the `src` attribute, so your assertion that using `img` tags necessarily makes a page static is just wrong.

Comment: @torazaburo If you feel i'm in the wrong for my reply, why did you delete your original comment? You asked why use ajax and suggested to place the image into an `img` tag. I'm explaining why someone might want to use ajax to get the image path. Request images path: Use ajax to call a server-side page that returns a either one or more image paths `image/someimage.jpg` depending on the server-side formatting for the output.

Comment: @NewToJS There is some kind of gap here in terms of what we are talking about. You seem to be talking about getting back strings giving the path of an image. Right, then that path is stuck into the `src` attribute of an image tag, either already on the page, or created dynamically. But the OP says explicitly "an image that is loaded on screen by an Ajax". This is where I am getting confused. Ajax does not load or display images. It just makes network requests. There is no way to tell, but it sounds like the OP wants to know when the image is loaded, not when the Ajax request completed.

Comment: @torazaburo meaning the ajax it returning the **path** of the image within the ajax response... you find this hard to follow? I would recommend you stop with the smart arse comments if you can't understand. Anything else you would like me to explain to you since you're having a hard time understanding?

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery AJAX's `.done()` function to handle such requirements.

Here is the sample code :

```
  $.ajax({
      //ajax code
    })
     .done( function() { 
       alert("Success!")
    })
     .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
     })
     .always(function() {
       alert( "complete" );
   });
```

Here is a link for more clarification :  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**EDIT : 1**

You can check for certain events on the image, as follows :

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .on('error', function() { console.log("error loading image"); })
;
```

**EDIT : 2**

Although you have tagged **`javascript`** in your question, in the answer I have used a **`jQuery`** code.

In case you are not aware about how to use jQuery. It is very simple you need to only refer to the CDN or you can download it from here : http://jquery.com/download/.

Note any version is good for your question.

You can also use a CDN link from various so , one of them being : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js

Comment: This isn't going to check the image has loaded or display a button. "i want a button to appear after the image is **fully loaded**"

Comment: I believe .done is fired when the ajax call is complete ?

Comment: Correct but just because the ajax call is complete it doesn't mean the images have loaded. Large images can take time to render in the browser.

Comment: Much better, shame jQuery isn't tagged in the question though but the OP might be interested in using it if this answer works for him/her. One last recommendation, show how to link to the jQuery library to make your answer usable to the OP. Some people don't know how to use jQuery hence not tagging it into questions so it's always a good idea to give a quick explanation of how to use and link to the library.

Comment: I would do that now! Thank you

Comment: I doubt if anyone cannot figure out how to load jQuery, since it's said to be used on 63% of the world's websites. The more pertinent question is why one would even think of using jQuery (especially since the question is not so tagged) for the simple operation of assigning an event handler. jQuery is over. Move on.

Comment: Hope someone explains the downvote ! :) maybe it will help me!

Comment: @torazaburo Some new developers might not know jQuery exists so your statement is incorrect. Just because many websites use it doesn't mean everyone knows of it. Many people visit websites and have no idea what library or language is used.

Comment: @NewToJS We'll have to agree to disagree. You are proposing that every single one of the hundreds of thousands of answers on SO that involves jQuery provide information for people who have never heard of it? If they have not heard of it, I heard there are ways to search the interwebs, for instance you could issue the command https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery.

Comment: I like your sarcasm but it isn't getting you very far. Would you like some time to read the question again? Don't delete your posts.